# Some pfBlockerNG feeds do not work but others do

Tags: pfsense

However, when I add feeds for firehol and binarydefense to my pfBlockerNG it says that there aren’t any domains listed. I have other feeds that work fine including EasyList.

When pfBlocker does an update I get the following output

> [ firehol_level3 ] Reload . completed .
>
> No Domains Found
>
> [ binarydefense ] Reload . completed .
>
> No Domains Found

Any tips on what I am doing wrong?

````
Format: Auto
State: ON
Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ktsaou/blocklist-ipsets/master/firehol_level3.netset
Label: firehol_level3

Format: Auto
State: ON
Source: https://www.binarydefense.com/banlist.txt
Label: binarydefense

List Action: Unbound
Update Freq: Every hour```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dumb and put the two feeds, which are lists of IP addresses, into the DNSBL feeds instead of the IPV4 feeds.

To block lists of IP addresses in pfBlockerNG go to IPV4/IPV6 menu and add the feed there.